# List of all suffixes of a list on Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need a predicate that gives me all the suffixes of a list on Prolog.

For example:

```
?- suffixes([1,2,3], X).

X = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], []].
```

I tried this and it works, but I can't use the findall function to get all of them in a single list.

```
suffix(Xs, Ys) :- append(_,Ys,Xs).

suffixes(Xs, Ss) :- findall(S, suffix(Xs,S), Ss).
```

Answer (score 2):

You may roll your own implementation of a list walking that yields every suffix:

```
suffixes([], [[]]).
suffixes([Item|Tail], [[Item|Tail]|Suffixes]):-
 suffixes(Tail, Suffixes).
```

Sample run:

```
?- suffixes([1,2,3], Suffixes).
Suffixes = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], []].
```

Answer (score 2):

In page 5 of [Representation Sharing for Prolog](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1311.pdf):

```
all_tails([],[[]]).
all_tails(L,[L|S]) :- L = [_|R], all_tails(R,S).
```